# Python conda traceback: No module named ruamel.yaml.comments

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Ran `conda update conda` on bash terminal and below is the traceback.

Any idea on what is wrong with my installation?

```
yusuf@yusuf-pc2:~$ conda update conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/conda", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conda==4.2.7', 'console_scripts', 'conda')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 567, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2612, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2272, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2278, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq, CommentedMap  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml.comments
yusuf@yusuf-pc2:~$
```

Location of ruamel package:

```
/home/yusuf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/comments.py
/home/yusuf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel_yaml/comments.pyc
```

The path needs to be corrected. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I got the same error with when installing conda 4.3.0.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu Hey. I found the solution. Check in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from Argonauts (superuser.com):

> It looks like you have two instances of anaconda installed on your
>   system. One installed to /usr/local/ and the other to your home
>   directory.
>
> From the bash shell, modify your path (temporarily) with this command:
>
> export PATH="/home/yusuf/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
>
> Then try updating again:
>
> conda update conda
>
> That should resolve the issue. You can then add the export PATH...
>   line to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file and the fix will be
>   persistent.
>
> Assuming that I guessed correctly about the cause of this issue,
>   you'll want to remove the duplicate installation - as long no other
>   system users are using it.
>
> To clean up the duplicate installation issue, under normal
>   circumstances you can remove an unwanted anaconda install simply by
>   deleting it - however since you have it installed to /usr/local/ you
>   will need to be very careful - other applications may be installed to
>   that directory. Simply renaming /usr/local/bin/conda to
>   /usr/local/bin/old.conda and the same for each /usr/local/bin/python*
>   entry shoud be enough to prevent that install being used, but it's far
>   from a perfect solution.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1159792/conda-traceback-no-module-named-ruamel-yaml-comments